# Adding string in new line of file if next line contains a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I have tried different solutions to solve this but none of them worked and were too messy to post here. So I will just present my problem. I have a `.txt` file that looks like this:

```
Field1:
Something
Field2:
Something
Field3:
Field4:
Field1:
Something
Field2:
Field3:
Something
Field4:
Something
...
```

The file contains 4 fields which repeat themselves an unspecified number of times but it always ends with `Field4`. Each field either has a string written under it or does not. Whether a field has something written under it or not is also random. In case it does not, I have to insert a string underneath which says `"Empty"`. So in the end it should look something like this:

```
Field1:
Something
Field2:
Something
Field3:
Empty
Field4:
Empty
Field1:
Something
Field2:
Empty
Field3:
Something
Field4:
Something
...
```

My thought process was to open the original text file as readable and another text file as writable, iterate through the lines of the original and write each line in the output file. If a line contains `Field1` and the next line contains `Field2`, then add string `Empty` underneath `Field1` and continue doing this for each line.

Comment: That's one way of doing it. What's your question?

Comment: @MattDMo How do I translate that solution to workable code?

Comment: so, go step by step. do you know how to "open the original text file as readable"? if you know how to do it, make code that does it and post it. if not check a tutorial on how to do it, like this https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/ Then you can move to the next point of the process "iterate through the lines". At the end you will have a code that does what you need

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Do you have to do this with multiple files or just one? If it's just one, it's quite easy to do in any decent programming editor like Sublime or Notepad++ with regex search and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since text files cannot be edited in the middle, the program reads every line in readable.txt and append them to writable.txt with correcting lines.

```
file = open("readable.txt","r")
file = file.readlines()
f = open("writable.txt", "a") 
n = 0

while n < len(file):
   if "Field" in file[n]:
       f.write(str(file[n]))

       if "Field" in file[n + 1]:
           f.write("Empty\n") 
           n = n + 1 
           continue
       else:
           f.write(file[n + 1]) 
           n = n + 1 
           continue
   else:
       n = n + 1
       continue

file.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large file, you don't want to read it all into memory before processing it, so you can do it line-by-line.

First, we can define a regex `pattern` to match the word `"Field"`, followed by any number of digits, followed by a colon. [Try the regex](https://regex101.com/r/euZV1E/1)

Each time you read a line, if the previous line matches this pattern and the current line also matches the pattern, you write an `"Empty"` before writing this line. If not, you just write this line:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"Field\d+:")  # Field, followed by one or more digits (\d+), and a colon

with open("in.txt") as infile, open("out.txt", "w") as outfile:
    prev_line = ""
    for line in infile:
        if pattern.match(line) and pattern.match(prev_line):
            outfile.write("Empty\n") # Write an Empty line if both lines match the pattern:

        outfile.write(line) # This is outside an if because we always write the current line
        prev_line = line
```

With your input file, this gives:

```
Field1:
Something
Field2:
Something
Field3:
Empty
Field4:
Empty
Field1:
Something
Field2:
Empty
Field3:
Something
Field4:
Something
```